# How do I disable WMDRM

Tags: windows-7

I'd like to disable WMDRM on win7.  I'm not looking to crack anything, or strip rights from a(ny) file(s).

I have plenty of files that are DRM free, and I don't want MS to get its hooks on them, or to see them.

I don't care that I won't be able to see some new things that come with DRM, or access some new services (if WMDRM is even still in existence?). I'd like WMDRM not sucking up processor power and/or making connections out, nor making lists of what I own or view.

Answer (score 1):

1. DRM in Windows Media Player can be turned off easily: in *Tools*/*Options*/*CD Audio* uncheck *Enable Digital Rights Management*.
2. Third-party tools such as [DoNotSpy78](http://windowsreport.com/windows-7-8-1-privacy-donotspy78/) can disable Windows Media DRM Internet Access. With any such tools, read reviews and check the installation file with [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/).
3. Adobe DRM, "Adobe Digital Editions", needs to be uninstalled if present. [N.B This has been cited for scanning *all* files on a PC, not just those being used.](http://www.networkworld.com/article/2692523/microsoft-subnet/adobe-digital-editions-allegedly-spying-scanning-pcs-uploading-logs-to-servers.html)

Comment: I have windows media center?

Comment: Do you? If that is a statement, see http://www.thegreenbutton.tv/forums/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=3760

Comment: Well, it was a statement - I did a search on "media" and didn't find wm player, but did find wm center.  Obviously, it didn't have the option you mentioned (and I didn't see anything similar).  There's VLC on the machine from the refurbisher, but not sure what would break if I removed WMC, so haven't yet.  One hit on virsustotal for donotspy78, but downloaded anyway.  Searched for, but did not find DE4.  Not a fan of adobe (so contemplating straight removal of all adobe), but I need to find a PDF replacement reader before stripping them out.  These are some nice links you've provided.